# Probability of 3 x 3 matrix will be non singular

Tags: probability-theory

There is a 3 x 3 matrix with real entries. Find the probability that the matrix will be non singular.

Comment: For real entries the probability should be zero.

Comment: I couldn't understand.. Please explain

Comment: @user363727 Why don't you first tell us what probability measure, or simply measure, are you using? It is not that hard to show that the  "usual" Lebesgue measure of any space of dimension $\,<n\;$ in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is zero, and thus the set of singular matrices has measure zero...and this could explain why the probability (**this probability** ...) of singular  matrices is zero...

Comment: Contrary to a previous comment I would claim that the probability should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square matrix is nonsingular iff its determinant is nonzero.

$$\left |\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & k
\end{bmatrix}  \right |=a(ek-fh)-b(dk-fg)+c(dh-eg)$$

Probability of $a(ek-fh)-b(dk-fg)+c(dh-eg)$ being nonzero is $1$.

Take any values $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$. This creates a relation between $h$ and $k$

$$\alpha k + \beta h$$

$$\alpha k + \beta h=0$$ is a line

$$\alpha k + \beta h \neq 0$$ is a surface without one line.

Under these circumstances, the probability of hitting the line is $0$.

(Nothing changes even if you take natural, rational, algebraic or complex numbers.)